# Unspecified Error in OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() function within SSIS script task

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I have an SSIS package, which has a FOREACH loop container and inside the loop I have a script task. The code in the script task is as given below

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Math
Imports Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Configuration

<System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version:="1.0", Publisher:="", Description:="")> _
<System.CLSCompliantAttribute(False)> _
Partial Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
Public Sub Main()
Try
            Dim oleConn As New OleDbConnection()
            Dim strConn As String = Dts.Variables("ConfiguredValue").Value.ToString()
            oleConn.ConnectionString = strConn
            Dim oleDA As New OleDbDataAdapter()
            Dim dt As New DataTable()
            oleDA.Fill(dt, Dts.Variables("Source_Data").Value)
            oleConn.Open()
            Dim oleComm As New OleDbCommand("Insert_Into_Destination")
            oleComm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            oleComm.Connection = oleConn
            oleComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", dt)
            oleDA.InsertCommand = oleComm
            oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery()
            oleConn.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Value of the variable Dts.Variables("ConfiguredValue").Value changes in each iteration of the For Each container. And it looks like -

```
"Data Source=server_name;Initial Catalog=db_name;User ID=user_id;Password = Password;Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;"
```

The problem is - when the package is executed there is an exception thrown at the ExecuteNonQuery() which shows 'Unspecified Error'.

There is no error when I try the similar code to insert an integer value. Issue is caused when it is a datatable I pass as the input parameter to the SP.

Any solution to avoid this?

Comment: You cannot pass a `DataTable` to a stored procedure .You need to eitehr use Table Value Parameters(TVP) or xml .Check out this MSDN link `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx`

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are missing is to tell the parameter what TVP it should be and it's type (last 2 lines). My [table valued parameter](http://billfellows.blogspot.com/2010/06/t-sql-tuesday-007-summertime-in-sql.html) is in C# but the same concepts will apply.

```
    command = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("TwitterAdd");
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.Connection = connection;

    // Assigning a table valued parameter looks much like any other parameter
    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlParameter tvp = command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", dataTable);

    // this is the only special sauce
    tvp.SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured;
    tvp.TypeName = "dbo.MY_TABLE_VALUED_PARAMETER";
```

This in VB should be the same minus the semi-colon.

Comment: Thanks @billinkc. I guess I was able to do the task with SQLConnection in my previous exercises. But here I have to use OleDbconnection itself, inorder to fill the data in the object Source_Data into a datatable(using oleDA.Fill method). My problem with datatable occurs when I use a oleDbConnection.

Answer (score 0):

I've hit the same issue.  The error message I was getting was:
"Command parameter[0] '' data value could not be converted for reasons other than sign mismatch or data overflow."

In the MSDN article referenced above I cannot see any reference to OLE DB - TVPs seem to be SqlClient only.

Also, in the `System.Data.OleDB.OleDbType` enumeration there is no option for Structured.

I changed my OLEDB connection to ADO.Net Connection and it worked fine.